# Backing out staged changes in Mercurial on a Mac

Tags: macos, mercurial

I just cloned an `hg` project that is typically maintained by Windows users (I'm an a Mac). I just did an `hg add .` and got a bazillion of the following messages:

```
adding out/blah
adding out/meh
adding out/fizz
adding out/buzz
...etc.
```

*I do not want anything under `out/*` getting committed & pushed!* So I added the following entry to `.hgignore`:

```
out/*
```

And then re-ran `hg add .`. **Have I successfully prevented all this cruft living under `out/*` from being committed & pushed to the remote repo?** If not, what else (specifically) do I need to do, and in what order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check with

```
hg status
```

which files were actually added (you can also use `hg status -a` to restrict yourself to added files). Unless you removed them, the files in `out` still remain added. In order to get rid of them, use:

```
hg forget out
```

Then use `hg status` or `hg status -a` again to verify that they are no longer part of the planned commit.

I'll also note that `out/*` will also exclude any files in subdirectories that are named `out`, e.g. `foo/out/bar.txt`. To ignore only files in the directory `out` at the root, use the following line instead for your `.hgignore`:

```
re:^out/
```

The `re:` prefix will use regular expression matching instead and `^out/` will match all paths that start with `out/`.

Comment: You forgot just one moment "Ask collaborators **always** have `.hgignore` **versioned**"